# "message": "Must have admin rights to Repository." for GitHub checked by audit logs

Tags: java, postman, github-api

I am using Github API with the personal access token, from a standard GitHub account.and
using "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token" this URL get the oauth access token. But I am using personal access Token logs are displayed but i am using oauth access token audit logs not displayed ..
i am still getting:

{
"message": "Must have admin rights to Repository.",
"documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/orgs#get-audit-log"
}

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/issues/1812. You must give admin rights when creating a personal access token. Create a new token with admin fields checked and it should work.

Comment: yes. it worked but i have create new access token in postman and get the new oauth access token. Using ouath token audit logs not displayed.